# Aloe Vera and Diabetes

Tags: diabetes, topical-cream-gel, blood-sugar, aloe-vera, insulin-resistance

I've read some research about it. Does Anybody know what substance in  Aloe Vera  can help in decreasing blood sugar in patients with diabetes?

And also is there any substance in Aloe Vera that is proven to decrease Insulin Resistance?

Answer (score 3):

[This study](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jcpt.12382/full) did a thorough literature search of all existing Aloe Vera research and found, at best, weak conclusions:

> The current evidence suggests some potential benefit of Aloe vera in improving glycaemic control in prediabetes and type 2 diabetes. However, given the limitations of the available evidence and the high heterogeneity in study results, high-quality, well-powered randomized controlled trials using standardized preparations are needed to quantify any beneficial effects of Aloe vera on glycaemic control.

On that basis, I am not sure if your premise (Aloe Vera helps in decreasing blood sugar in patients with diabetes) holds true. I do not know of any study that has actually identified helpful substances in Aloe Vera for diabetes and do not think there is any [study].

Diabetes as a disease seems to attract crackpots and crackpot theories. I have a child with Type 1 Diabetes. Every month I must meet 4-5 people who come to me with ridiculous theories and substances that will cure diabetes or improve it: cinnamon, coriander, beet juice, dried mango, pineapple, "natural substances that reverse diabetes." It is an experience common to all of us, parents of children with diabetes or people with diabetes: just look at how mocking savvy diabetes forums are towards the diabetes diet of the day.

The sad truth is that there is nothing. For Type 1s, insulin is the only thing that can help. Many Type 2s will be helped by diet, exercise and some oral medicines -- but, for most of them, they will eventually graduate to insulin too. In fact, that would be true for all of them -- except that some will die of something else first.

There is no magic bullet:(